# aptly publish snapshot operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, mirroring, aptly

I'm trying to build a local mirror of the ubuntu repository using aptly and I'm hitting an "operation not permitted" error at the point of publishing.  Here is what I'm doing;

I've created 3 mirrors

```
$ aptly mirror create -with-udebs xenial \
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe multiverse

$ aptly mirror create -with-udebs xenial-updates \
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main universe multiverse

$ aptly mirror create -with-udebs xenial-security \
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  xenial-security main universe multiverse

$ aptly mirror update xenial
$ aptly mirror update xenial-updates
$ aptly mirror update xenial-security
```

created 3 snapshots

```
$ aptly snapshot create snap-xenial          from mirror xenial
$ aptly snapshot create snap-xenial-updates  from mirror xenial-updates
$ aptly snapshot create snap-xenial-security from mirror xenial-security
```

merged them

```
$ aptly snapshot merge snap-merged snap-xenial snap-xenial-updates snap-xenial-security
```

and now I want to publish, which is where I hit the error

```
$ aptly publish snapshot -distribution=xenial snap-merged
Loading packages...
Generating metadata files and linking package files...
ERROR: unable to publish: unable to process packages: link /media/user/usbdrive/aplty/full/pool/00/6f/a3e766cc601510d78861ac2f15d2_0ad_0.0.20-1_amd64.deb /media/user/usbdrive/aplty/full/public/pool/main/0/0ad/0ad_0.0.20-1_amd64.deb: operation not permitted
```

My .aptly.conf file looks like this

```
{
  "rootDir": "/media/user/usbdrive/aplty/full",
  "downloadConcurrency": 4,
  "downloadSpeedLimit": 0,
  "architectures": ["amd64"],
  "dependencyFollowSuggests": false,
  "dependencyFollowRecommends": false,
  "dependencyFollowAllVariants": false,
  "dependencyFollowSource": false,
  "dependencyVerboseResolve": false,
  "gpgDisableSign": false,
  "gpgDisableVerify": false,
  "gpgProvider": "gpg",
  "downloadSourcePackages": false,
  "skipLegacyPool": true,
  "ppaDistributorID": "ubuntu",
  "ppaCodename": "",
  "skipContentsPublishing": false,
  "FileSystemPublishEndpoints": {},
  "S3PublishEndpoints": {},
  "SwiftPublishEndpoints": {}
}
```

I've looked at the permisions on the directories and they look ok

```
 $ ls -al /media/user/usbdrive/aplty/full/public/pool/main/0/0ad/
 total 64
 drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 32768 Aug 19 20:29 .
 drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 32768 Aug 19 20:29 ..
```

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and I am using an external drive with a fat32 partition over thunderbolt3 to store the files.  And I know that there is a aplty/aptly typo in the path but I don't believe that is the problem.

I'd really appreciate some pointers on what I'm doing wrong or how else to debug this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aptly is using hard links by default when publishing repositories: it hard links files in the package pool (cache for all the package files) to the location under directory `public/`.

FAT32 doesn't support hard links, so publishing fails with this error. I would recommend to use some Unix filesystem for best efficiency, but if that is not possible, you can configure [another publishing endpoint](https://www.aptly.info/doc/feature/filesystem/) with `copy` link method which copies files (so each published repository takes additional space), but it should work on FAT32.